# Argument of \blx@defformat@i has an extra }

Tags: biblatex, compilation-error

I am writing my PhD Thesis on Overleaf and I am using a template that I found online and adapted to my university guidelines. I am very new to LaTeX and a basic user.

Since around a month ago, I haven't been able to compile my thesis on Overleaf even though no error is shown. Due to this, I downloaded LaTeX onto my Mac but when I try to compile the document, I get this error message: `Argument of \blx@defformat@i has an extra }` in reference to line 92 (bibliography settings that I modified to make them fit my university guidelines).

This is part of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[
12pt,
openany,
english, 
onehalfspacing,
headsepline, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\hyphenpenalty=1000 % preventing splitting of words
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[format=plain,margin=25pt,font=small,labelsep=colon]{caption}

\newcommand{\foo}{\foo}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------                 BIBLIOGRAPHY SETTINGS UNIGRAZ  ---------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear,sorting=nyt,sortcites=true,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=3,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=true,backref=false,backend=biber,maxbibnames=20,innamebeforetitle=true,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash} %slash between names
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\renewcommand{\bibpagespunct}{\addcomma\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1} %remove "pp"

\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{#1}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
  \printfield{volume}
   \setunit{\addcolon}
  \printfield{number}
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{number}{\addcolon{#1}} %volume:issue
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{article}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}
  {} %comma after title of articles
  
  
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  urlfrom = {in},
}
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}} %url as "in"
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]
**\usepackage{xpatch}** %here error while compiling
\xpatchbibdriver{misc}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \newunit}
  {\usebibmacro{title}%
   \printunit{\addcomma\space}}
  {}
  {}%comma after titles of articles in websites
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibbrackets{\bibstring{urlseen}#1}}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{urlseen ={}} %url in square brackets without "accessed on"


\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %lastname first

\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace} %no period after year

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addcolon}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1} %quotes (year:page)


\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
\DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
  \renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}} %incollection with title, :in editor (ed.)

\DeclareLabeldate{\field{year}\field{eventdate} \field{origdate}\literal{nodate}} % n.d. in sites when no year

\addbibresource{example.bib} % The filename of the bibliography

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography

\setlength\bibitemsep{0.5\baselineskip} % space between bibliography entries
```

Answer (score 3):

The line before the marker `%here error while compiling` is faulty.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]
```

is simply incomplete. The syntax of `\DeclareFieldFormat` is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[<entry type_1,...,entry type_n>]{<field>}{<formatting code>}
```

The offending line is missing the two mandatory arguments. I can't guess what the two arguments should have been, so in order to make this error go away, I suggest you just delete this line.

Note that Overleaf should show you an error for this faulty line even if it generates a PDF output.

Indeed if I try

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

as in https://www.overleaf.com/read/rvgqqbfngrrv

I get one error reported by Overleaf (see the red box with the 1 next to the "Recompile" button - highlighted in pink)

[image: error number shown on Overleaf]

Overleaf can be pretty good at hiding error messages from you. That's why you should **always** make sure that your document is error free. See also [Examples of Overleaf users not noticing error messages](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7898/35864).

Comment: Thanks - I changed `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}} %url as "in"
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]
**\usepackage{xpatch}`to `\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{url}{\bibstring{urlfrom}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}`. Overleaf still does not work and I don't get any errors reported. TexShop now compiles the pdf file but it does not load my bibliography and I get the "please (re)run Biber" notification.

Comment: @Mnk96 Clear the cache on Overleaf (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache) and try again. Assuming you have cited something in your document, you should either get bibliography output or warnings/errors. (I can't say anything more useful since I don't know what your document actually looks like.)